# Is the French word “parfait” compound?

Tags: étymologie, mots-composés

One can notice that the word *parfait*, which literally translates to *perfect* in English seems to contain two distinct French words.

First, *par*, which is sometimes rendered in English as *per* (as in miles per hour) meaning 'by'.

Secondly, the verb *fait*, possibly a conjugation of the verb *faire* meaning 'to do'. Maybe, [according to Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/fait), *fait* here means 'fact'.

Putting these together to get "per action" or maybe "per fact".

Comment: The wiktionary gives you the answer straight away. *[Parfait*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parfait) is the past participle of the verb [*parfaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parfaire) that is derived from the verb *faire* plus the prefix *-par*. I expect most French people won't see it a compound word nowadays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer: Technically, no, but your reasoning is not really false.**

Two ways to see it:

**1. Parfait can be considered the past participle of the verb "[parfaire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parfaire)"**, which is neither a compound word in the French sense (two French words put together) nor in the English sense, as "par" is here technically a "préfixe", that is a particle commonly put behind the radical to form the word, like "parvenir", "parcourir", "parachever". It is, you guessed it correctly, a variant of *per*, meaning "through" in Latin.

**2. Parfait, like its English counterpart *perfect* and other European words is in fact derived from the Latin "perfect passive participle" *[perfectus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perfectus)*** and is as such a single, non-compound word. *Perfectus* like its basic form *perficio*, is composed of *per-* (through) + *facere* (to do) meaning "to carry out".

However, although that basic form *perficio* is composed of multiple morphemes in Latin, it's still not a compound, but a derivation. Compounds are  [considered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)) to be formed from two different independent lexemes, instead of an affix + an independent lexeme. While Latin did have a word *per*, what is present in *perficio* and many such words is the prefix [*per-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per-#Latin) (etymologically connected, of course).

I like to give these two similar explanations because they highlight the particularities of European Latin etymologies.

Comment: Indeed — so many words in Romance languages (and languages they were borrowed into) can be broken down etymologically, but  functionally have just one base today. I edited this answer to clarify the difference between compounding and derivation. (I gather from your answer that you know this, but overlooked the fact that Latin words like this are formed from affixes rather than independent lexemes.) Feel free to change my wording if you want.

Comment: Good edit. I just changed 'infinitive' to 'basic form' (that's how we called this when Iearned Latin) as a compromise between simplicity and correct grammatical wording.

Comment: Thanks! Slip of the tongue... of the mind?... on my part.